# Brownian motion as markov processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I just wanted some clarification. I presume the second equation is incorrect? And shouldn't independence imply $E[\{W(t) - W(s)\}|I_s] = E[W(t) - W(s)]$ which is 0 rather than $E[W(t) + W(s)]$?

[image]

Comment: $E[W(t) + W(s)]=0+0=0$!

Comment: Yes but why does the sign change from -ve to +ve?

Comment: where does the $\mathbb{E}[W(t)|W(s)]$ come from in the second equation?

Comment: @LSK21 No idea. I was just verifying that these are indeed typos :)

Comment: I might be forgetting something since it's been some time since I worked with Brownian motion, but I remember the property just being $\mathbb{E}[W(t)|\mathcal{F}_s] = W(s)$.

Comment: You're right it's just a typo